# Get a value out of a socket.io function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io

I am trying to create a function that will return the value of answer. However I am having trouble in getting this value out.

What it is currently doing is getting some data from the server and storing that in data. However I am wanting to make this value easier to get to as to not have to constantly wrap my content within the serverAnswer function. Is this possible to do?

```
var serverAnswer = (function() {
    var answer;
    socket.on("server answer", function(data){
        answer = data.year;
    });
    return function() {
        alert(answer);
    };
}());

serverAnswer();
console.log(answer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't exactly do that in a synchronous way. However you can create a function where you want that `answer` value and call that from socket callback. or even socket callback can be your function where you want to utilize `answer` value.

```
function doit(answer){
    // do something with answer
}
```

You can do this

```
socket.on("server answer", function(data){
    answer = data.year;
    doit(answer);
});
```

Or this

```
socket.on("server answer", doit);
```

Comment: You are a legend good sir. What is different about socket.on("server answer", doit); ?

Comment: @factor_za `doit` is actually that function that we are passing in first case. we just named it `doit` and placed it outside and then used its reference

Comment: great. I used the first method and now can pass that through my main function.Thanks!